# Hibernate gives error error as "Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set" when there is no internet connection

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate works fine when there is internet connection. But when there is no internet connection, it gives me

> Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

error. I think my application is trying to access the internet connectivity when running. The detail error that I get is given below:-

> Dec 22, 2015 6:17:43 PM
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator
>   initiateService
>       WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
>       Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>       org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:209)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.hibernatefiles.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:32)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.hibernatefiles.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:44)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.main.AdminModule.start(AdminModule.java:21)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Exception in Application start method
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.hibernatefiles.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:39)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.hibernatefiles.hibernate.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:44)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.main.AdminModule.start(AdminModule.java:21)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(Unknown
>   Source)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
>         ... 1 more
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
>         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:209)
>         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
>         at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
>         at com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.hibernatefiles.hibernate.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:32)
>         ... 11 more
>       Exception running application com.pos.admin.admin_module.main.AdminModule

My pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.pos.admin.admin_module</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin_module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>admin_module</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

<!--    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build> -->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>javax.el</groupId> <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2.4</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId> 
            <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId> <version>2.2.4</version> </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My hibernate configuration (hibernate.cfg.xml) file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/point_of_sales</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- 
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>  -->

        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.Category"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.ProductHeader"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.PurchaseDetail"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.PurchaseHeader"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.SalesDetail"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.SalesHeader"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.Settings"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.Unit"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.hibernatefiles.dto.Supplier"/>

<!--         <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.Supplier"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.PurchaseHeader"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.ProductHeader"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.Category"/>
        <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.Unit"/> -->
  <!--       <mapping class="com.pos.storekeeper.storekeeper_module.hibernateFiles.dto.User"/> -->

        <!-- <mapping class="com.pos.admin.admin_module.admin_module.main.Cart1"/> --> 

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil class where I create `Configuration` and `Session` objects

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate-annotation.cfg.xml
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            try{
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception while handling configureation file :" + e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("asfsdaf " + configuration);
            }
            System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation Configuration loaded");

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            System.out.println("Hibernate Annotation serviceRegistry created");

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if(sessionFactory == null) sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void closeSessionFactory(){
        if(!sessionFactory.isClosed()){
            System.out.println("Closing SessionFactory");
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fix this issue because internet connectivity cannot be always available. Thank you

Comment: Post your code where do you have configuration

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use hibernate offline you will have to change your dtd in  your xml mapping and configuration files.make sure hibernate jar is in your classpath

```
for xml mapping file
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM 
        "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

for configuration file :

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

http://www.journaldev.com/2959/how-to-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-work-offline

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `SessionFactory` from this:

```
SessionFactory  sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

To be:

```
   sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Or add this  `buildSessionFactory()` like this:

```
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I actually don't know what service registry does. Please can you explain me

Comment: @pranishres you can choose one of both suggestions and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Hibernate has the ability to auto-configuring the Dialect, once its been able to establish a JDBC connection. If you can't establish a JDBC connection, that might be the problem.

Comment: I dont think hibernate will auto configure the dialect.  I created this SO and I tried removing dialect settings from my application.properties in this post but that did not change anything.