# Hibernate4+Spring4 org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

Tags: spring, hibernate

need some help guys.
I'm just learning to use both Spring and Hibernate, so I might have made a basic mistake somewhere, but I just can't figure out where.
I try to run my app on a tomcat 8 server, I use BoneCP as DataSource implementation and MySQL, I build it without Maven. I got no problem before

I have my Spring XML file **springdispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="main.statisthira"/>
<context:property-placeholder location="WEB-INF/properties/gers.properties"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"><value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value></property>
    <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>

<bean name="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
    <property name="username" value="gers"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
    <property name="user" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/statisthira"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
</bean>

<bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

</bean>

<bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean name="songNewDAO" class="main.statisthira.dao.SongNewDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Then my Hibernate XML configuration file **hibernate.cfg.xml**. hibernate.dialect is explicitly defined, but nothing happens

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <mapping package="main.statisthira.model"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I try to use the sessionFactory in a simple DAO

```
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public class SongNewDAO implements ISongNewDAO{

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public Song getSongById(String id){
            return (Song) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().byId(id);
        }

        public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
            return sessionFactory;
        }

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

no error at compilation, but when I try to access one of my controller that uses the DAO, I get a long error message, ending with :
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:205)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:630)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:678)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm working offline, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416166/hibernate-gives-error-error-as-access-to-dialectresolutioninfo-cannot-be-null-w) suggested to make some change in the

**web.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

my Controller Home.java

```
Controller
```

@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Home {

```
@Autowired
private ISongNewDAO songNewDAO;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String helloWorld(ModelMap model) {
    Song song = songNewDAO.getSongById("0isp4utk4v");
    model.addAttribute("song", song);
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world");
    return "home";
}

public ISongNewDAO getSongNewDAO() {
    return songNewDAO;
}

public void setSongNewDAO(ISongNewDAO songNewDAO) {
    this.songNewDAO = songNewDAO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the location of your hibernate configuration file in your sessionFactory bean:

```
<bean name="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I totaly missed that thanks. but now i'm given a http 404 error `07-Mar-2017 08:30:26.073 WARNING [http-nio-8088-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/statisthira/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springdispatcher'` yet, in my web.xml file, I have `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>` plus the controller  `@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class Home ...`

Comment: Please post your web.xml and your controller Home class.

Comment: Please try path /home not /statisthira/home

Comment: that solved the problem (now i have other error messages, but that's something else). but what explains that change of behaviour after I started integrating Hibernate? because before that, I accessed that controller with /statisthira/home

Comment: If you want to prefix all paths with **statisthira** in your exposed endpoints then change your servlet-mapping to 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/statisthira/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: thanks. actually, now that it works, it doesn't bother me much that there's the **statisthira** prefix or not, but i just try to figure out why there was a behavior change (though I beleive I made no change to mappings)